# How to delete all files in folder after specific time

Tags: php, time

I am using this code to delete all files in folder

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/';
        $op_dir=opendir($dir);
        $x = 5; 
        $current_time = time();
        $difference = $current_time - $x;

        while($file=readdir($op_dir ))
         {
                 if($file != "." && $file != ".." ){
                     var_dump($dir.$file);
                   unlink ($dir.$file);
                 }
        }
        closedir($dir);
```

But I need to do this action after specific time for example after 6 month all files in the folder should be deleted.I searched more but all codes are related to file creation date not generally specific time.

Comment: Do you want to execute this as a scheduled event or on each page load? Are you running windows or linux?

Comment: I want to delete all files after 6 month not depending on page load

Comment: How ca i create php script correctly and where I need to put this code.Am using wordpress CMS

Comment: do you have ssh access to your server, can you install new cron jobs?

Comment: no dont have.did you have an idea doing it with php @Alex Andrei .Is it posssible?

Comment: it's possible, but you should really inspect your hosting panel, "cpanel" or whatever for cron options, since you will still need to schedule the php script anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84548/discussion-between-anahit-ghazaryan-and-alex-andrei).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the action as cronjob.
Read the following link: [Crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

You also can save a date in a database and consult in top of the script if 6 month have elapsed.

Comment: I didbnt have any experience with this Crontab and that's why I need to do it with PHP.Can you help me with this @Tobias?

Comment: Thank you.I found a way working with crontabs and done it!

Answer (score 0):

How  to  calculate  starting time  for  6 months  so we can take  directory creation time or save the particular time in a database  for calculation .The  best option is cronjob for this task